# Functions definitions with variable arguments

Tags: functions, function-construction, argument-patterns

How do you define a variable amount of functions with a variable amount of arguments? I don't get [the reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsWithVariableNumbersOfArguments.html) at all :

```
    Clear["Global`*"]
    ClearAll[Subscript]
    n = 3;

    cost = Table[Subscript[c, i], {i, n}];
    Do[Subscript[c, i] = RandomInteger[{0, 400}]/1000, {i, n}];
    price = Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, n}];
    equations = Table[Subscript[eq, i], {i, n}];

 Do[Subscript[eq, i] = 
       Subscript[p, i] - Subscript[c, i] + 
        1/(Sum[Subscript[p, l]*Boole[l != i], {l, n}]), {i, n}];

    Do[Subscript[p, i] = Symbol["p" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}];
    g1[p1_, p2_, p3_] := Evaluate[equations[[1]]];
    g1 @@ {0.1, 0.1, 0.2}
```

I need to be able to generate `g1..gn` functions with arguments `gi[p1,..pn]`, is there a way to make it with some kind of loop `{i,n}`?

I tried something like this without success:

```
Do[Symbol["g" <> ToString[i]][p__] := Evaluate[equations[[i]]], {i, n}]
```

I also wonder how do I explicit that the first argument is p1, the second is p2... and the nth is pn.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit about the functions that you are trying to create? As it is, it's hard to parse what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a system of equations that NSolve/FindInstance can't handle. So I'm trying to work a fixed point for several variables convergence with this. (btw the equation above is a dummy, not the real problem)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this by generating `Function`s rather than expressions involving formal arguments. And instead of trying to give symbols indexed names, I'd make the index a parameter.

So, instead of the eventual function call looking like this:

```
g1[0.1, 0.1, 0.2]
```

I want something more like this:

```
g[1][0.1, 0.1, 0.2]
```

But we have to deal with a couple of issues. First, `g[1]` is ambiguous, because we don't know what the "order" is (you set this in your code with a global `n`). So, one parameter isn't enough. We'll need something like this:

```
g[n, i][<list of n args>]
```

where `n` is the order (3 in your example) and `i` is the `i`th function among the group of `n` functions.

Next, we need to deal with the randomness of `cost`. We could work the randomness into our definition for `g`, but I don't like having that hidden effect. So, we'll add yet another parameter for `cost` (and you can still generate a random value if you want to pass in). So, we want to define something like:

```
g[cost_, order_, index_] := Function[<...need to figure this bit out...>]
```

Using `Function` relieves us of the problem is coming up with unique argument names, because we can use `Slot`. For kicks, I'll memoize this as well. So we end up with something like this:

```
g[cost_, order_, index_] := 
  g[cost, order, index] = 
    Function[
      Null, 
      Evaluate[cost + Slot[index] + 1/Plus @@ Delete[Array[Slot, order], index]]]
```

Let's try it out:

```
g[c, 3, 1][x, y, z] (* c + x + (y + z)^(-1) *)
g[c, 4, 3][w, x, y, z] (* c + y + (w + x + z)^(-1) *)
g[1, 4, 2][1, 2, 3, 4] (* 25/8 *)
g[RandomReal[], 2, 2][1, 2] (* I got 3.495947182193526 *)
```

One slight, potential problem is that we're not checking the number of arguments passed. So, something like `g[1, 4, 2][1, 2, 3]` will generate error messages and produce a not-very-useful output. But your original formulation had basically the same problem, but you'd just get an unevaluated `g1` (or whatever) instead of error messages.

You might consider making `cost` an argument to the `Function` rather than a parameter of `g`.